# When I click one image, all images get highlighted! Any thoughts?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a border to the image upon click, and also use the cookies plugin to keep the clicked style active even after refreshing. While I managed to keep the styles to stay after refreshing the browser, now I have the problem of not being able to click the images individually.

When I click one image, all the images get hightlighted.

```js
 $(function() {
    var img_class = $.cookie('img_class');
    if(img_class) {
        $('img').attr('class', img_class);
    }
 $(' img').click(function() {
       $(this).each(function() { 
         $("a img").toggleClass("active");
         $.cookie('img_class', $('img').attr('class'));
    });
 
 });
 });
```

```css
/* less styles */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);  
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);  


@background: #333;
@maxHW: 100px;
@textClr: #999;
@borderClr: #fff;
@standardMarg : 5px;
@fontFamily: "Raleway", sans-serif;

body 
{
  background-color:@background !important;
}

.page-header {
  h2
  {
   color: @textClr;
   font-family: @fontFamily;
  }
}
  
.row {
      .col-lg-4, col-sm-6,  col-xs-12
   {
      padding:0;
   max-height:@maxHW * 3; 
      max-width:@maxHW * 3;
         margin:@standardMarg;
   }
   }  
  
a {
    
 display:block;
 max-height:@maxHW * 3;  
 max-width:@maxHW * 3;
 
     img  
  {
     max-height:@maxHW * 3; 
  max-width:@maxHW * 3 ;
  border:4px solid @textClr;
  }
 }
 
 .active
 {
   border: 4px solid @borderClr;
 }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image1.jpg" class=" img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image4.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image5.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image6.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image7.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image8.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="img/image9.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
   </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because you are toggle classes to all elements, when toggling a class all the elements that match your selector you will add the class to all elements that are not having the class and removing the class from elements with `.active` so you should check out `$.removeClass` and then add the class to current element.

Try using this code

```
$(function() {
    var img_class = $.cookie('img_class');
    if(img_class) {
        $('img').attr('class', img_class);
    }
    $('img').click(function(e) {
        $('a img').removeClass('active');
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
        $.cookie('img_class', $(e.currentTarget).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Erm, kinda solved the first problem, but now I have the cookies issue. I can click the images individually, but the styles disappear upon refreshing.

Comment: It should do, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkm5qg1t/3/) Maybe you got some other errors?

Comment: I'm afraid it's still problematic. Thanks anyway! I'm going to forget about this stupid cookie stuff!

Answer (score 0):

`.toggleClass()` will switch the state of the class. If it's applied, it will become unapplied, and vice-versa. The problem is that you click one image, and then apply the active class to ALL of your images by using `.toggleClass()`.

Try something like this:

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
    $("a img").removeClass("active"); // deactivate all others
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass("active"); // activate this one
});
```

edit_________________

You should be careful about how you are using jquery selectors. `$('img')` will select ALL of the img tags in the entire html document. You need to select a specific img tag, and you will need a unique identifier to do that. In the example below, I chose to use `src` because (I'm assuming) there are no two imgs with the same src.

```
$(function() {
    var selected_img_src = $.cookie('selected_img_src');
    if(selected_img_src) {
        // this is selecting ALL img tags. Not just the one you want.
        //$('img').attr('class', img_class);

        // find the img with the saved src and make it active
        $('img[src="'+selected_img_src+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
    $('img').click(function(e) {
        ...
        // save the src as a unique identifier for the image
        $.cookie('selected_img_src', $(e.currentTarget).attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I did manage to solve the images problem, but now the styles won't stay after refreshing. I'm pulling my hair out right now :(

Comment: Cookie is a separate issue. You need to store which image is selected (the index or src or something unique to that image), and re-select that image based on that information. I'm not even sure what your current code is doing, but it's not even close to what it needs to be. I can try appending my original answer...

Comment: You sir, are a genius!!! That somehow solved most of the problem. I'll add few tweaks, and then we're good to go. Thank you!!